# Mounting Hadoop files system

Tags: hadoop, ubuntu-12.04, hdfs, fuse

I have followed the following link to mount HDFS as local file system

http://solutionsatexperts.com/hadoop-fuse-installation-and-configuration-on-centos/

After downloading the hdfs-dfs, they mentioned to install rpm package. As per link, I have switched to root and typed the command

```
yum install fuse*
```

But it shows

```
There are no enabled repos.
Run "yum repolist all" to see the repos you have.
You can enable repos with yum-config-manager --enable <repo>
```

can any one help me to solve this

Comment: you have to add the repository in your repo file.

Comment: Thanks @Bector...I tried but failed..can u share me link for adding repository

Answer (score 0):

I succeed in installing hadoop-hdfs-fuse to mount hdfs as local file system by following this [guide](http://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-5-x/topics/cdh_ig_hdfs_mountable.html) from cloudera.
You can add such [file](https://archive.cloudera.com/cdh5/redhat/6/x86_64/cdh/cloudera-cdh5.repo) to /etc/yum.repos.d/, as reference [here](http://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/latest/topics/cdh_ig_yumrepo_local_create.html#topic_30) :

```
[cloudera-cdh5]
# Packages for Cloudera's Distribution for Hadoop, Version 5, on RedHat or CentOS 6 x86_64
name=Cloudera's Distribution for Hadoop, Version 5
baseurl=https://archive.cloudera.com/cdh5/redhat/6/x86_64/cdh/5/
gpgkey=https://archive.cloudera.com/cdh5/redhat/6/x86_64/cdh/RPM-GPG-KEY-cloudera    
gpgcheck=1
```

Do some adjustment according to your os version.